# How should I know the valid subresource_names of different Azure services to set a private-link for them?

Tags: azure, terraform

I am following [this document](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/private_endpoint) to create a private-link for different resources (**keyvault**, **Databricks**, **DataFactory** and **mssql database**).

```
resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "endpoint" {
  name                = format("%s-%s", var.name, "private-endpoint")
  location            = var.resource_group_location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  subnet_id           = var.subnet_id

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = format("%s-%s", var.name, "private-service-connection")
    private_connection_resource_id = var.private_link_enabled_resource_id
    is_manual_connection           = false
    subresource_names              = var.subresource_names
  }
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_a_record" "dns_a" {
  name                = var.asset_name_which_use_endpoint
  zone_name           = var.zone_name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  ttl                 = 10
  records             = [azurerm_private_endpoint.endpoint.private_service_connection.0.private_ip_address]
}
```

As you can see, I have to fill the requiered `subresource_names` value of each of resources. However, I don't know what is the proper value ?

I have checked [this page](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/private_endpoint) and [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-overview#private-link-resource) but still have no clue about the valid values.

So, my question is, what is the valid `subresource_names` values for the **keyvault**, **Databricks**, **DataFactory** and **mssql database** ?

Comment: I have no experience with this service either so I'm just guessing based on what I see in the docs. Hopefully someone else will add something more decisive. I _think_ the intent of the Microsoft docs is that the value values for `subresource_names` are the keywords in the "Subresources" column, depending on what type of resource you are connecting your endpoint to.

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial below already defines subresources for private links; the keywords in "Subresources" depend on the type of resource you are connecting. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-overview#private-link-resource) , [Databrick](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/azure/private-link)

what is the valid `subresource_names` values for the **keyvault**, **Databricks**, **DataFactory** and **mssql database** ?

**Answer:**

Find below list of Subresources you are looking.

- mssql  - **sqlServer**
- Databrick - **databricks_ui_api**
- DataFactory       - **dataFactory**
- keyvault -  **vault**

Replicated the sample code base with SQL server and data brick, find below source code for reference

****NOTE:  There will be errors related to GroupId when connecting to a third-party resource. The reference code base is from HashiCorp**. [site](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/private_endpoint)

```
data  "azurerm_client_config"  "current" {}
resource  "azurerm_resource_group"  "example" {
name  =  "v-swarna-mindtree"
location  =  "West Europe"
}
resource  "azurerm_sql_server"  "example" {
name  =  "myexamplesqlservernew"
resource_group_name  =  azurerm_resource_group.example.name
location  =  azurerm_resource_group.example.location
version  =  "12.0"
administrator_login  =  "******"
administrator_login_password  =  "******"
tags  =  {
    environment = "production"
}
}

resource  "azurerm_sql_database"  "example" {
name  =  "myexamplesqldatabase"
resource_group_name  =  azurerm_resource_group.example.name

location  =  azurerm_resource_group.example.location
server_name  =  azurerm_sql_server.example.name

}

resource  "azurerm_databricks_workspace"  "example" {

name  =  "databrickstest"

resource_group_name  =  azurerm_resource_group.example.name

location  =  azurerm_resource_group.example.location

sku  =  "standard"

  

tags  =  {

Environment = "Production"

}

}

resource  "azurerm_virtual_network"  "example" {

name  =  "example-network"

address_space  =  ["10.0.0.0/16"]

location  =  azurerm_resource_group.example.location

resource_group_name  =  azurerm_resource_group.example.name

}

resource  "azurerm_subnet"  "service" {
name  =  "service"
resource_group_name  =  azurerm_resource_group.example.name
virtual_network_name  =  azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
address_prefixes  =  ["10.0.1.0/24"]
enforce_private_link_service_network_policies  =  true
}
resource  "azurerm_subnet"  "endpoint" {
name  =  "endpoint"
resource_group_name  =  azurerm_resource_group.example.name

virtual_network_name  =  azurerm_virtual_network.example.name

address_prefixes  =  ["10.0.2.0/24"]

  

enforce_private_link_endpoint_network_policies  =  true

}

resource  "azurerm_public_ip"  "example" {
name  =  "example-pip"
sku  =  "Standard"
location  =  azurerm_resource_group.example.location
resource_group_name  =  azurerm_resource_group.example.name
allocation_method  =  "Static"
}

resource  "azurerm_lb"  "example" {
name  =  "example-lb"
sku  =  "Standard"
location  =  azurerm_resource_group.example.location
resource_group_name  =  azurerm_resource_group.example.name

frontend_ip_configuration {
name  =  azurerm_public_ip.example.name
public_ip_address_id  =  azurerm_public_ip.example.id
}
}
resource  "azurerm_private_link_service"  "example" {
name  =  "example-privatelink"
location  =  azurerm_resource_group.example.location
resource_group_name  =  azurerm_resource_group.example.name
nat_ip_configuration {
name  =  azurerm_public_ip.example.name
primary  =  true
subnet_id  =  azurerm_subnet.service.id
}

load_balancer_frontend_ip_configuration_ids  =  [
azurerm_lb.example.frontend_ip_configuration.0.id,
]
}

resource  "azurerm_private_endpoint"  "example" {
name  =  "example-endpoint"
location  =  azurerm_resource_group.example.location
resource_group_name  =  azur
subnet_id  =  azurerm_subnet
private_service_connection {
    name  =  "example-privateserviceconnection"
private_connection_resource_id  =  "/subscriptions/********************/resourceGroups/*******/providers/Microsoft.Network/privateLinkServices/example-privatelink"  //azurerm_private_link_service.example.id
is_manual_connection  =  false
subresource_names  =  ["databricks_ui_api"]
}
}
resource  "azurerm_private_dns_zone"  "example" {
name  =  "****.com"
resource_group_name  =  azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}
resource  "azurerm_private_dns_a_record"  "dns_a" {
name  =  "dnsprivate"
zone_name  =  azurerm_private_dns_zone.example.name
resource_group_name  =  azurerm_resource_group.example.name
ttl  =  10
records  =  [azurerm_private_endpoint.example.private_service_connection.0.private_ip_address]
}
```

**terraform plan as follows:**

[image]

Verification after apply
[image]

Comment: That's perfect. I will check it and let you know. Meanwhile, could you please take a look on my other question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74726785/how-to-create-azure-storage-account-gen2-with-no-public-access