# How to create Azure storage account Gen2 with no public access?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-data-lake-gen2

I wish to create a `Azure Storage Account Gen2` using the Terraform, with **NO PUBLIC ACCESS**.
It means that, my storage account and none of my nested containers should not be reachable in public network, because the access is possible via private-link. here is my code:

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storage_account" {
  name                            = var.storage_account_name
  resource_group_name             = var.resource_group_name
  location                        = var.resource_group_location
  account_tier                    = "Standard"
  account_replication_type        = "LRS"
  account_kind                    = "StorageV2"
  is_hns_enabled                  = "true"
  allow_nested_items_to_be_public = false
  public_network_access_enabled   = false

}

resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem" "data_lake_storage" {
  name               = "rawdata"
  storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.storage_account.id
}

resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem" "processed_data_storage" {
  name               = "processeddata"
  storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.storage_account.id
}
```

Although, I am working with `Storage Account Gen2`, still i expect [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/anonymous-read-access-configure?tabs=portal) be helpful. So, I was expecting that the below attributes make it private for me:

```
allow_nested_items_to_be_public = false
  public_network_access_enabled   = false
```

However when i run the code, i got these two errors:

```
│ Error: checking for existence of existing File System "rawdata" (Account "formuleinsstorage"): datalakestore.Client#GetProperties: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Or
iginal Error: autorest/azure: error response cannot be parsed: {"" '\x00' '\x00'} error: EOF
│
│   with module.storage_account.azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem.data_lake_storage,
│   on modules\storage-account\storage_account.tf line 14, in resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem" "data_lake_storage":
│   14: resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem" "data_lake_storage" {
│
╵
╷
│ Error: checking for existence of existing File System "processeddata" (Account "formuleinsstorage"): datalakestore.Client#GetProperties: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403
 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: error response cannot be parsed: {"" '\x00' '\x00'} error: EOF
│
│   with module.storage_account.azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem.processed_data_storage,
│   on modules\storage-account\storage_account.tf line 19, in resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem" "processed_data_storage":
│   19: resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem" "processed_data_storage" {
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce in my environment:

**Terraform code:**

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storage_account" {
  name                            = var.storage_account_name
  resource_group_name             = var.resource_group_name
  location                        = var.resource_group_location
  account_tier                    = "Standard"
  account_replication_type        = "LRS"
  account_kind                    = "StorageV2"
  is_hns_enabled                  = "true"
  allow_nested_items_to_be_public = false
  public_network_access_enabled   = false

}

resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem" "data_lake_storage" {
  name               = "rawdata"
  storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.storage_account.id
}

resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem" "processed_data_storage" {
  name               = "processeddata"
  storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.storage_account.id
}
```

***I got the same error:***

[image]

When I created the data lake storage without giving those attributes at all:

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storage_account" {
  name                            = var.storage_account_name
  resource_group_name             = var.resource_group_name
  location                        = var.resource_group_location
  account_tier                    = "Standard"
  account_replication_type        = "LRS"
  account_kind                    = "StorageV2"
  is_hns_enabled                  = "true"
}
```

And when given ***`Storage blob data contributer`*** access:

[image]

It is created successfully without error.

[image]

The storage is created and by default , showing as private:

[image]

And not able to access its files.

[image]

**Note:**
Once the account is created , I tried to give the values .

```
allow_nested_items_to_be_public = false
  public_network_access_enabled   = false
```

Then its not showing error and code run successfully  but there isn’t much difference as there are by default private.